# How to restart X server?

Tags: nvidia, lightdm, 15.10, xserver

First of all I should say that I have very limited computer knowledge so go easy on me. I have Ubuntu 15.10 installed on my laptop and I was trying to to install the driver for the Nvidia video card but an error kept popping up saying that the x  server was on so the installation cannot be completed, so I disabled lightdm and went into the tty terminal and installed the driver (which was a .run file btw) from there, after I was done I started it again but the computer seemed to freeze so I rebooted it now I'm stuck in the login screen and whenever I type my password it just sends me back to the same screen. 
I tried going back into the tty and typing 
sudo start lightdm 
But it said that it failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart. 
Btw sorry I'm using my phone so I can really format stuff properly. 
Update: typing

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

Yields this output

[image]

Again I apologize for taking a picture of the screen but I can't really do much from my laptop right now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command. It is a wrong way to install drivers this way.

Comment: @Pilot6 did that

Answer (score 1):

You can install Nvidia driver for your adapter by running:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some broken packages pending while you tried to install the Nvidia drivers. Try

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then try to `sudo service restart lightdm` again.

Comment: Still the same issue :/